# add 1 hour to time to entire column on sheet load

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a spreadsheet that has a column with a time in it, I need some vba to run that adds 1 hour to every cell in the time Column. the column does not have a fixed length.

Comment: Best if you try something and then post what you've tried here (along with a description of any errors) if you run into trouble.

Comment: I have tried ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.value + TIME(1,0,0) but all I get is a mismatch error.

Comment: `ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.value + 1/24`

Comment: Or `ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.value + TimeSerial(1,0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Why these kinds of questions get voted down I don't know. Everyone has a different ability to be specific about the question they're asking. If you don't know enough about a question to need help on it how are you going to be specific about what you need? Anyhow, here's how to do it:

1) Identify the column number the data is in e.g. column A = 1, B = 2 etc.
2) Get the last used row of the data, something like this:

```
lastRow = theWorksheetTheDataIsOn.Cells(theColumnNumber, 1000000).end(xlUp).row
```

This goes from row one million upwards and finds the first row that has data on it.

3) Then you can go from the first row (I'll assumse this is row 2) to the last row you just identified in step 2, like this:

```
For x = 2 to lastRow

     theWorksheetTheDataIsOn.Cells(x, theColumnNumber) = DateAdd("h", 1, Cells(x, theColumnNumber))

Next x
```

The DateAdd formula is what you're looking for. A good explanation can be found here http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php